# KendoUI Scheduler Custom Time Marker

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

We are using the Kendo UI Scheduler component and we need to display a custom time marker like the one for the current time.

Is this possible and what would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of accomplishing this is inserting a `div` element into `div.k-scheduler-times` using jQuery:

```
$("<div class='new-time-marker'></div>").prependTo("tr:nth-child(2) .k-scheduler-times");
```

You can set its style attributes with css to be similar to the regular marker. The position can be calculated based on the scheduler's properties and then applied to this `div`.

You can add the time marker after the scheduler is loaded. For instance, if you use the method that appears in the documentation - `$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({...});`, you can add the time marker right after that block.

To set the top value of the time marker, you can use percentage which you can calculate:

```
$(".new-time-marker").css("top", ((9*60+22)*100/(24*60)) + "%");
```

In this example, the marker will appear at 9:22. You can also do it this way of course:

```
$(".new-time-marker").css("top", ((9+22/60)*100/24) + "%");
```

Add styling like this one:

```
.new-time-marker {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-6px);
}
```

the transform will make sure the center of the marker is right where you pointed it.

Comment: Hey Shai, that's great! It works well, but there are some more aspects to forge the whole solution: 1) when should I add the time marker? 2) how to calculate its "top" value?

Comment: I've implemented an AngularJS directive that implements all the details. Hope it will be helpful - https://gist.github.com/nedyalkov/15ca8b3d8431464cc843b4e9ff57271d

Comment: This is a great solution! I've implemented an example in a dojo here: http://dojo.telerik.com/oWeSi/13

That prepends the marker in the dataBound event so it shows up at all times (in case that may be necessary), but uses scheduler table slots to determine its offset position. I had trouble in the dojo with the calculation in the answer as it was putting it around 9:40ish instead of 9:22.